# Integer and fractional pars of Gaussian random variables

Tags: calculus, probability, normal-distribution

Are there any interesting results known about integer and fractional parts of $\xi \in \mathcal N(0, \sigma^2)$? In particular, I am interested in their expected values and covariance matrix.

Comment: Are the integer and fractional parts of $-2.4$ equal to $-3$  and $+0.6$ or equal to $-2$ and $-0.4$?.  If the former then expected values will be $-\frac12$ and $+\frac12$. If the latter, then the expected values will be $0$ and $0$.

Comment: Partially answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2190258).