# Explicit calculation of the sum of an infinite series given by integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability

Let $0\le a < b \le1$ and $\phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2}$. I want to know if the following statement is true:
$$
\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} \int_{n+a}^{n+b} \phi(x) dx = b-a,
$$
where the summation runs over all integer numbers.

It is correct if $a = 0, b=1$, since $\phi$ is the density of the standard normal distribution. It is also correct if $a = 0, b= 1/2$ by some arguments with symmetry. Is it correct for arbitrary choice of $a$ and $b$? Is there elementary approach to prove it?

Comment: Should there be an $n$ in your integral?

Comment: Thanks and it is corrected. The upper index and lower index are depending on $n$.

Comment: It is not true if $a = 0, b = \frac{1}{2}$. You cannot include the interval $(\frac{1}{2}, 1)$ for example

Comment: @Paul Let $X \sim \mathcal N(0, 1)$ and $\{ X \} = X - \lfloor X \rfloor$. The identity is true for $(a, b) = (0, 1/2)$ because
$$\mathbb P(\{ -X \} > 1/2) =
\mathbb P(-X - (-\lfloor X \rfloor - 1) > 1/2) =
\mathbb P(\{ X \} < 1/2)$$
and $-X \overset d = X$.
But the distribution of $\{ X \}$ [is not uniform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2190258/).

Comment: @Paul Instead you have $(-1,-{1\over 2})$ so everything is fine.

Comment: @Maxim thanks, although it is really unfortunate result.